# Overlay closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay, opacity

I have an overlay:

```
<div id="overlayer" class="overlayer">
<div id="board" class="board"></div>
</div>
```

With these css properties:

```
#overlayer
{
position:fixed;
display:none;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #807980 0%,
        #3d323d);
background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#807980),
        to(#3d323d));
        opacity:0.6;
        z-index:9998;
}

#board
{
position:relative;
left:33%;
top:20%;
width:600px;
height:450px;
border-radius:15px;
background-color:white;
z-index:9999;
display:none;
}
```

And I'm triggering it with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function overlayerOn(){
    $('#overlayer').fadeIn(800);
}

function overlayerOff(){
    $('#overlayer').fadeOut(800);
};

$('#fr').click(function(e){
    overlayerOn();
    var $br = $('#board');
    $br.css('display', 'block');
    });

$('#overlayer').click(function(e){
    overlayerOff();});

});
</script>
```

But when I'm closing the overlay I would like it to close only on clicking on overlay, but my script is closing even when I click on div in middle of overlay. Any idea? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the propagation of the event:

```
$('#board').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

See also

- [W3C: DOM Level 3: Event dispatch and DOM event flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)
- [MDN: `event.stopPropagation`](https://web.archive.org/web/20120525113633/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation)

Answer (score 0):

This is called [event propagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), you can stop this by preventing the `click` event from propagating up the DOM by adding `e.stopPropagation();` when clicking on the `board` element like this :

```
$('#board').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding:

```
$("#board").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Did you mean something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah dude, the trick is using the e.target property
Replace the close function with this and you should be sweet:

```
$('#overlayer').click(function(e){
    if (e.target === $('#overlayer')[0]) {
     overlayerOff();
    }
});
```

This is all to do with event bubbling, have a read of this bad boy and you should understand it quick:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

see [SO duplicate Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385113/howto-div-with-onclick-inside-another-div-with-onclick-javascript)
basically you should prevent event propagation on the inner div,

```
$("#board").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); //except on IE this works
});
```