# js click events of nested elements

Tags: javascript

I have a list with div items. each of them redirects to a page when I click it. 
Now I added a button within the div and I do not want to get redirected when I click the button (i.e. do not execute the parent divs on click event)

```
<div class='item' onClick="alert('div');">
... div content
    <button class='btn' onClick="alert('button');">Action</button>
</div>
```

Above code should only alert once when I click the button.

EDIT:

I just realized that my actual problem is even one more level up:

```
<a href='www.google.at'>
<div class='item' onClick="alert('div');">
    <button class='btn' onClick="alert('button');event.stopPropagation();">Action</button>
</div>
</a>
```

I need to prevent the href redirection when I click the button. Is there something similar to event.stopPropagation()?

Comment: See MDN [*Event.stopPropagation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [*Howto: div with onclick inside another div with onclick javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385113/howto-div-with-onclick-inside-another-div-with-onclick-javascript).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Original answer**

You can accomplish this by calling event.stopPropagation()

```html
<div class='item' onClick="alert('div');">
    <button class='btn' onClick="alert('button');event.stopPropagation();">Action</button>
</div>
```

**Answer to edit**

Apparently you can stop the propagation to an anchor element by returning false, not sure if this is the proper way, but it works.

```html
<a href='www.google.at'>
<div class='item' onClick="alert('div');">
    <button class='btn' onClick="alert('button');event.stopPropagation();return false;">Action</button>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you. It works for the click events, but I just realized that my problem is actually one more level up and related to a href. (please check my edited question)

Comment: I just discovered event.preventDefault(); :)