# Ignore div click if click was on button inside div

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a div with a button inside of it that minimizes the div. If you click anywhere else inside the div it will load details about the div.  However, I don't want to load details if minimizing the div.  Here is my code:

```
<div (click)="showDetails(key)" *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <button (click)="minimize(key)">Minimize</button>
    <span>The rest of the content is here</span>
</div>
```

When minimize is triggered, I want to ignore showDetails.

Comment: This might give you more insights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385113/howto-div-with-onclick-inside-another-div-with-onclick-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not able to test it right now, but what you could try is

```
(click)="minimize(key, $event)"
```

In your component

```
minimize(key, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Try with either one of them and see how it goes !

Answer (score 4):

what you have to do is to ignore the parent click event by stopping the propagation of the event using `stopPropagation()`

html code :

```
<div (click)="showDetails(key)" *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <button (click)="minimize(key,$event)">Minimize</button>
    <span>The rest of the content is here</span>
</div>
```

ts code :

```
minimize(key,event){
       event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **event.stopPropagation()**
to prevent the click event from bubbling up the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

What i did here to get around it pretty simple where you do not need create the function/method.

```
<div (click)="showDetails(key)" *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <button (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Minimize</button>
    <span>The rest of the content is here</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually now that i read this, they likely need to do more with the click event but when i searched for an answer, this is all i needed. Still hope it helps someone :)